# SwiftUI: List scrolls up on selection of a row when there's `.id(UUID())`

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

I have a list with selecting rows and a search bar. **Search bar freezes up the list**, but I fixed that using `id(UUID())`

It created another problem, in which when user taps on a row, **scroll jumps to top**. Sometimes, when selecting few rows it **crashes** with this error: `precondition failure: attribute failed to set an initial value: 96`

```
struct ContentView: View {

@ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
@State private var searchText: String = ""
@State private var selected = Set<Model>()

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        SearchBar(text: $searchText, placeholder: "Search")
        List(
            viewModel.strings.filter({ searchText.isEmpty ? true : $0.title.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) })
        , selection: $selected) { model in
            MultipleSelectionRow(selectedItems: self.$selected, model: model)
        }
        .id(UUID()) /// This line causes strange behaviour.
    }
  }
}
```

The full project is available on [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/dosboxd/question) with other screencasts and files like selection view, search bar and viewModel.

[image: Screencast shows jumping scroll view]

Comment: Not sure, but I think UUID() is causing problems, it will create a new one each time body is reloaded and is thus not a stable id. But really not sure... just a hunch

Comment: `.id(UUID())` rebuilds entire List every view refresh... Actually it is not clear what do you try to achieve in general, because currently it looks like you try to fix fixes.

Comment: @Asperi yes, I try to fix fixes, because `.id(UUID())` slows down search and I don't want that happening. Is there any ways to prevent jumping a list or speeding up search? There's a link to GitLab repo with other 2 screenshots.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain **why** you are using `.id(UUID())`. What do you think that modifier is doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

There're initially two ways to use list, but each one had it's own bugs.

1. When using SearchBar, keyboard and list was freezing.
2. Use .id(UUID()) to fix freezes, but it adds another misbehavior: list scrolls to top every time selecting row. And it used to crash.

I ended up using UITableView with UIViewRepresentable. When I replaced List with UITableView, I added property `@Binding var offset: CGFloat` and updated it every time row is being selected:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
    offset = tableView.contentOffset.y
    return indexPath 
}
```

Sorry for unclear question, it was clear in my mind back then. Thank you for trying to help.